# thread safety in GNUTLS

Tags: c

The version of GNUTLS is 3.5.                                                   I want to use a child thread to handshake with remote peer.
In my child thread, I just use `gnutls_handshake()`.

1. In the parent thread, can I use `pthread_cancel()`  to cancel the child thread safety regardless of the current handshake state?
2. If I have registered the pull/pull_timeout/push functions with `pthread_cleanup_push`/`pthread_cleanup_pop`,
   can I cancel the child thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have emailed Nikos Mavrogiannopoulos(current maintainers of gnutls) ,his answer as follow:

gnutls functions were never designed as pthread cancellation points. I
have not thought that much, but I believe your main concern is memory
leaks right? It may be that if you deallocate the session in another
thread it may just work; though you may have to create a stress test
for that to verify that this is possible.